# Button click event in aspx

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm using Page with tabs, In 3rd tab i have search functionality But whenever i click search button page will reload and it will move to first tab.
I need tab should stay constant after button click, How can i do that?

```
<body class='default'>
<div id='jqxWidget'>
    <div id='jqxTabs'>
        <ul>
            <li style="margin-left: 30px;">UserTickets</li>
            <li>JavaServer Pages</li>
            <li>Active Server Pages</li>
            <li>Python</li>
            <li>Perl</li>
        </ul>
        <div>


        </div>
        <div>

        </div>
        <div>
        <form runat="server">


            <asp:Button ID="button" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:search()" Text="search" />
            <asp:Label ID="label" Text="" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div>

        </div>
        <div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using AJAX to only refresh the content on that tab. It wont refresh the whole page and go back to the starting tab then.

Comment: I'm new to AJAX, can you please tell any site which is usefull

Comment: I have added my answer, if you follow my steps it should work. Please mark as correct if it worked and you found it useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax is probably the best bet in the situation you are in. The best way to describe it is that it will just refresh content on the page that you have wrapped the AJAX around. The problem your having it that on button click it is causing the page to reload therefore going back to the 'Starter' tab.

Here is a small snippet of code I have put together for you and I will explain what to do.

- You need to add Nugent Package to your project and add the 'Ajax Control Toolkit'.
- At the top of your code you need to add this line. *(Think of it as saying 'I want to use the toolkit on this page and i will call it using AjaxControlToolkit')*

  ```
  <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="AjaxControlToolkit" %>
  ```
- Then you need to add the line below to your page.

  ```
  <AjaxControlToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></AjaxControlToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
  ```
- Then wrap the lines of code for that tab with these lines of code.

  ```
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
      <ContentTemplate>

      </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
  ```

Make sure that you wrap all the information that tab inside the .

This is a very basic way of using AJAX and it can be used more advanced but this will work.

Comment: hi its working fine partly...i'm getting NewLIne in constant error         <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="AjaxControlToolkit" %> and data IN Label will not stay, I think that tab is getting refreshed.  Thank you for help it helped me lot:)

Comment: @user3664374 Its fine, if you need anymore help just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use update panel. In the third add update panel, below is the sample:

```
<div id="third-tab">
 <form>
  <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptMng"></asp:ScriptManager>
  <asp:Button ID="button" runat="server" Text="search" />
   <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="label" Text="" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlId="button" />
    </Triggers>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
 </form>
</div>
```

In the code behind try test below code

```
protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
 label.Text = "Searching without full reload";
}
```

Hope it's help

Answer (score 0):

You can set Tab on Page Load conditionally. Look at this code might it will help you.

```
    var TabNum=(Your Tab Number)
    function selecttabs() {
        $('[id$="dvInvoiceTab"]').tabs("select", TabNum);
    }
```